# How to map Items which its SubItems are in the same Table with Nhibernate?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mapping

I am trying to build a messaging system and for this i have the table definition below

Message

```
Id
From
To
Body
ParentId // Subcollection, i want to get Asnwers (Message.ParentId== Message.Id)
IsRead
```

and i have this in the Message.cs

```
IList<Message> Answers;
```

I have tried this but it gives me all the messages and all the answers in the main collection.

**But i dont want answers to be seen like a message (like the main item).**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="RealEstate.Core" namespace="RealEstate.Core.Domain">
  <class name="Message" table="Message" lazy="true">
    <id column="id" type="Int64" name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="From" column="[From]" type="Int64" />
    <property name="To" column="[To]" type="Int64" />
    <property name="Body" column="Body" />
    <property name="ParentId" column="ParentId" type="Int64" />
    <property name="SenderType" column="SenderType" type="Byte" />
    <property name="IsRead" column="IsRead" type="Boolean" />

    <bag name="Answers" lazy="true" cascade="delete">
      <key column="ParentId" />
      <one-to-many class="Message"/>
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can this mapping be done, they are in the same table ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to map a tree ?
Maybe this could help:
[how to map a tree in nhibernate](http://web.archive.org/web/20090806071731/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting an answer, I'd strongly recommend that you **search the [NHibernate Users Group](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers)** as there are tons of helpful NHibernate folks that lurk there answering all kinds of questions.

But let me see if I can help here.

Hmmm, I'm not totally sure I understand the question. You say:

> I have tried this but it gives me all
>   the messages and all the answers in
>   the main collection.
>
> But i dont want answers to be seen
>   like a message (like the main item).

Do you mean that the `Answers` collection contains all answers in the database?

Can you post up more code, showing the query your running, and the class code?

One potential problem you have with your scenario is that `ParentId` can be `NULL` in the database. This gives NHibernate problems when mapping a one-to-many.

Try making the association [bidirectional (documentation reference)](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/collections.html). That sometimes helps avoid a few traps.

To do that, add this to your class

```
public class Message {
  ///<summary>Reference to parent message</summary>
  public Message Parent {get;set;}

  //... rest of class
```

Add this to your mapping:

```
<bag name="Answers" lazy="true" cascade="delete" inverse="true">
   <key column="ParentId" />
   <one-to-many class="Message"/>
</bag>

<many-to-one name="Parent"/>
```

The `inverse=true` will make NHibernate manage the relationship from the Parent property, not the collection. This is necessary because ParentId can be null.

In your code, rather than using `myMessage.Answers.Add( blah );` you can use `answer.Parent = myMessage`. Of course, you can write nice helper methods to make this more meaningful.

```
someMessage.AddAnswer( someAnswer );
```

Which looks like this:

```
public void AddAnswer(Message answer)
{
   answer.Parent = this;  
   if( ! this.Answers.Contains(answer) )
      this.Answers.Add(answer);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but this is exactly what i m searching for http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate.aspx

thanks again